# meaning of "hop/simply hop"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

I saw this quotes somewhere on the internet and I can't understand the meaning of "hop/simply hop" on these quotes below:

"So they hop online, armed only with an avatar and their keyboard."
"They won't simply hop down."
"Simply hop on, start up and go."

I can't write here the context of each one, because I just saw them like I wrote here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "hop" can be a small jump; it is an easy jump.  We also use it to mean a quick and easy journey, for example a single stop on bus or train.

In the context you give "hop online" It suggests it is quick and easy to get online.   Similarly "hop down" suggests "it easy to get down. If they "won't hop down" it isn't because they are not able get down.  Moreover, "hop on, start up" suggests it is easy to get started (you don't need any special training, for example).